# Is the relationship between these two sequences, identical but for signs, trivial?

Tags: totient-function, mobius-function

Sums of divisors of product of first $n$ primes has same sequence as products of totients of first $n$ primes, but with alternating signs. [OEIS A005867](http://oeis.org/A005867)
*Mathematica* code shown:

> Table[Sum[
>     MoebiusMu[d] d, {d, Divisors[Product[Prime[j], {j, 1, n}]]}], {n, 1,
>      8}]
>   Table[Product[EulerPhi[Prime[j]], {j, 1, n}], {n, 1, 8}]

```
{-1, 2, -8, 48, -480, 5760, -92160, 1658880}
{1, 2, 8, 48, 480, 5760, 92160, 1658880}
```

**Edit** an alternate for the first statement:
$$\sum_{n=1}\ \sum_{(d_{1},\dots,d_{2^{n}})\ |\ \text{lcm}(p_{1},\dots,p_{n})}\mu(d_{m})d_{m}$$
Is this a trivial relationship?

Comment: One of these is  $\displaystyle n\mapsto \prod_{i=1}^n \varphi (p_i)$.  The other is $\displaystyle n \mapsto \sum_{I\subseteq\{1,\ldots,n\}} \prod_{i\in I} p_i$.  Is that what these are?  (I am not adept at reading the $\vphantom{\frac\int\int}$sort of code you've written here.) ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Why would one speak of the totient of a prime $p$ rather than just write $p-1$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, second is good. The first is more complicated. We take the divisors of the product of the first $n$ primes. The we sum those divisors while applying the sign using $\mu$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, I got the second line from OEIS,

Comment: You wrote "products of totients of first $n$ primes".  Should that be rephrased? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, possibly _partial_ products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\prod_{i=1}^n\phi(p_i)=\phi(\#_n),$$

where $\#_n:=\prod_{i=1}^np_i$, by multiplicity.

$$\sum_{d\  | \  \#_n}\mu(d)d$$

is your second sum.

Conjecture: for any $n$ that is a product of distinct, single power primes (e.g. $35=5\cdot 7$):

$$\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)d=(-1)^k\phi(n),$$

where $k$ denotes the number of $prime$ divisors of $n$, so for $n=35=5\cdot 7$, $k=2$.

Notice that $g(d)=d$ is multiplicative, so it suffices to establish the conjecture for $n=p$ prime:

$$\sum_{d|p}\mu(d)d=\mu(1)+\mu(p)p=1-p=-\phi(p).$$

Since $\phi(n)=\prod_{p|n} \phi(p)$ (remember $n$ has only single prime powers), so

$$\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)d=\phi(n)(-1)^k$$

So your observation has been proven.

Fun fact, for any integer $n$:

$\phi(n)=\sum_{d|n}\mu(n/d)d=\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)n/d,$

So you have kind of a mirror identity in your case. Neat!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is trivial — at least for some definition of trivial. The sum is literally a term-by-term expansion of the product of $(p_i-1)$; it iterates all the members of the product, with the sign of a given term $\Pi_{i\in S}p_i$ determined by the parity of the number of distinct primes $|S|$ in the individual term - in other words, by $\mu(\Pi_{i\in S}p_i)$.